# Ways to make parametric statistics work with real time (often non-normal) data

Tags: distributions, nonparametric, teaching

**BACKGROUND:**

I have been tasked with teaching basic data analysis methods with R to a group of people in a business setting.

While my stance is that I am most difinitely not at the level where I should be teaching anything about statistics to anyone, I really have no choice here.

The "syllabus" is expected to range from loading data to R and making a histogram, to becoming able to run multiple and logistic regressions.
**Assumption of normality and CLT will be covered**.

The issue I am facing is that I will be teaching mostly parametric statistics that largely rely on the data being normally distributed. However, the underlying expectation is that these methods would ultimately be applied to "real" data, which in this business often has irregular distributions.

**QUESTION**:

Is there a begginner-friendly way to normalize a distribution to a point where beginner-friendly stastical methods (z-scores, t-tests, ANOVA, etc.) would have meaningful/correct outcomes? Do I just create a distribution of sample means and call it a day?

Comment: The present question seems somewhat vague and broad.